# Subir archivos y datos con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form class="formuploadajax" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">
    <br>
    <input  type="email" id="correo" name="correo" placeholder="Escribe tu correo electronico"/>
    <br>
    <input  type="file" id="archivo" name="archivo"/>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Subir archivos" onClick="subirArchivo();"/>
</form>
```

Y tengo los siguientes scripts:

```
function subirArchivo()
{
    var formData = new FormData($(".formuploadajax")[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: '../includes/upload_archivo.php',  
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function(){
          $(".cargar-archivo").show();
          $(".cargar-archivo").html("<img src='../img/ajax-loader.gif'>");        
      },
      success: function(data){
        if(data != "error")      
        {
            $(".form-tarea").hide();
            registrarArchivo(data);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".cargar-archivo").hide();
            vex.dialog.alert("Error al subir archivo, intenta de nuevo");
        }
      }
    });
}

function registrarArchivo(archivo)
{
    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var correo = $("#correo").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../includes/acciones/archivos/insert_archivo.php",
      data: "nombre=" + nombre + "&correo=" + correo + "&archivo=" + archivo, 
      success: function(data)
      {  
        if(data == 1)
            $(".cargar-archivo").html(archivo);
        else
        {
            $(".cargar-archivo").hide();
            vex.dialog.alert("Error al subir archivo, intenta de nuevo");
        }
      }         
    });
}
```

upload_archivo.php

```
<?php
$path = '../archivos/';

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
{
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['archivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $nombre = uniqid(); 

    $path = $path.$nombre.".".$ext;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $path))
    {
       sleep(3);
       echo $nombre.".".$ext;
    }
    else
      echo "error";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

insert_archivo.php

```
<?php
include_once("../clases/class.Archivo.php");

extract($_POST);
# nombre
# correo
# archivo

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");
$hora = date("H:i");

$insertar = Archivo::insertArchivo($nombre, $hora, $archivo, $fecha, $hora);

if($insertar > 0)
    echo 1;
else
    echo 0;
?>
```

Lo que tengo que hacer aquí es subir un archivo al servidor y el nombre de ese archivo junto con los datos nombre y correo guardarlos en una base de datos.

Como pueden darse cuenta estoy usando el objeto FormData para mandar el archivo a php y poderlo subir al servidor, pero si observan primer ejecuto el método subirArchivo() qué es el que me sube el archivo, si el archivo se subió correctamente ejecuto el método registrarArchivo() que es el me registra la información en la base de datos.

La pregunta es si esto que estoy haciendo está bien??. Así como lo tengo si funciona pero tengo la duda si en un solo método puedo mandar a php tanto el archivo a subir como los datos que se tienen que guardar en la base de datos, en lugar de hacerlo en dos métodos.

Comment: Claro que lo puedes hacer con un solo método. Te pondré un ejemplo muy sencillo de la vida real. Si viajas a una ciudad que dista 500 km de donde vives y tienes que llevar varias cosas, ¿harías dos viajes para llevarlas pudiéndolas llevar en un sólo viaje? Lo mismo ocurre con las peticiones Ajax: son *viajes* llevando o trayendo cosas desde el cliente al servidor y viceversa. Un escenario en el que se justificarían dos métodos (dos viajes) sería que parte de la información que hay que llevar no esté lista y se necesite urgentemente la parte que esté lista para trabajar con ella...

Comment: @A.Cedano y como lo haría con un solo método??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu primer llamado Ajax ya tienes el nombre y correo en la superglobal `$_POST` de manera que podrías hacer:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    sleep(3);
    $archivo = $nombre . '.' . $ext;
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
    $hora = date("H:i");

    $insertar = Archivo::insertArchivo($nombre, $hora, $archivo, $fecha, $hora);
    if($insertar > 0) {
       echo $archivo;
    } else {
       echo 'error';
    }
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

En general correspondería revisar si `nombre` y `correo` vienen en el `$_POST` pero, en este caso, siempre vienen, sólo que podrían ser un string en blanco.

Podrías poner una comprobación tal que la petición ajax sólo se envíe si se cumple que:

```
formData.get('archivo').name.trim() !== '' &&
formData.get('nombre').trim() !== '' &&
formData.get('correo').trim() !== ''
```

**Sin embargo**, tu código ahora habrá quedado así (en el backend)

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['archivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $nombre = uniqid();

    $path = $path . $nombre . '.' . $ext;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        sleep(3);
        $archivo = $nombre . '.' . $ext;
        $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];
        $correo  = $_POST['correo'];
        $fecha   = date('Y-m-d');
        $hora    = date('H:i');

        $insertar = Archivo::insertArchivo($nombre, $hora, $archivo, $fecha, $hora);
        if ($insertar > 0) {
            echo $archivo;
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }

} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Tienes tres niveles de anidación y mucho código repetido. Podrías reescribir lo anterior encapsulándolo en una función que devuelve el nombre del archivo o bien 'error', metiendo cortocircuitos que devuelvan 'error' sin tener que anidar:

```
function manejarArchivo()
{
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
        return 'error';
    }
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['archivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $nombre = uniqid();

    $path = $path . $nombre . '.' . $ext;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        return 'error';
    }

    sleep(3);
    $archivo = $nombre . '.' . $ext;
    $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo  = $_POST['correo'];
    $fecha   = date('Y-m-d');
    $hora    = date('H:i');

    $insertar = Archivo::insertArchivo($nombre, $hora, $archivo, $fecha, $hora);
    if ($insertar <= 0) {
        return 'error';

    }
    return $archivo;
}

echo manejarArchivo();
```

Ahí te ahorraste todos los `else` y el código es más fácil de entender.

Comment: Entonces nada mas seria hacer ese cambio en el código php y en el código javascript solo seria dejar el metodo subirArchivo() así como lo tengo y borrar el método registrarArchivo(archivo), es correcto??

Comment: Correcto, no necesitas la segunda función